# SoapUI - Dynamically create request

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I need to create a request based on the response of a previous request. The response has the format as below. Basically, the response can have any number of groups which can each contain any number of questions
**Sample Response**

```
<Group>
  <Question>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Row>2</Row>
    <Code>1-6666</Code>
    <Text>my text</Text>
  </Question>
  <Question>
    <ID>2222</ID>
    <Row>3</Row>
    <Code>1-111</Code>
    <Text>my text</Text>
  </Question>
</Group>
<Group>
  <Question>
    <ID>4244</ID>
    <Row>0</Row>
    <Code>1-8888</Code>
    <Text>my textfgdfgd</Text>
  </Question>
</Group>
```

Sample request
For each group and question I need to include some data in the request

```
<Header Stuff>
 <UpdateTargets>
   <Group>
     <Question>
       <ID>1234</ID>
       <Row>2</Row>
       <NewValue>my updated value</NewValue>
     </Question>
```

...For each group and question appearing in the response

I'm not sure how to do this. I'm assuming some kind of groovy script.

Comment: Seems to have messed up my formatting

Comment: Messed up my formatting

Request
   <Group>
      <Question>
        <ID>1234</>
        <Row>2</Row>
        <Code>1-6666</Code>
        <Text>my text</Text>
      </Question>
      <Question>
        <ID>2222</>
        <Row>3</Row>
        <Code>1-111</Code>
        <Text>my text</Text>
      </Question>
    </Group>
    <Group>
      <Question>
        <ID>4244</>
        <Row>0</Row>
        <Code>1-8888</Code>
        <Text>my textfgdfgd</Text>
      </Question>
    </Group>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a groovy script testStep and inside it you can use `XmlSlurper` to read the content of your previous response and the `groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder` to create the new request from the previous data. See the follow code which I hope it's self explanatory:

```
// this is your xml hardcoded for the sample, but you can
// get it using the follow line
// def xml = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('SOAP Request').getPropertyValue('response')
def xml = '''<root><Group>
  <Question>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Row>2</Row>
    <Code>1-6666</Code>
    <Text>my text</Text>
  </Question>
  <Question>
    <ID>2222</ID>
    <Row>3</Row>
    <Code>1-111</Code>
    <Text>my text</Text>
  </Question>
</Group>
<Group>
  <Question>
    <ID>4244</ID>
    <Row>0</Row>
    <Code>1-8888</Code>
    <Text>my textfgdfgd</Text>
  </Question>
</Group></root>
'''

// parse the response from the previous testStep
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

// markup to create the request
def sw = new StringWriter()
def request = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
// create <UpdateTargets>
request.UpdateTargets {
    // for each <Group> in response create a group in next
    // request
    root.Group.each{ group ->
        Group {
            // for each <Question> in response create a question in next
            // request
            group.Question.each { question ->
                Question(){
                    ID(question.ID)
                    Row(question.Row)
                    NewValue('yourNewValue')
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}

log.info sw
```

This code logs your new request as:

```
<UpdateTargets>
  <Group>
    <Question>
      <ID>1234</ID>
      <Row>2</Row>
      <NewValue>yourNewValue</NewValue>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <ID>2222</ID>
      <Row>3</Row>
      <NewValue>yourNewValue</NewValue>
    </Question>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <Question>
      <ID>4244</ID>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <NewValue>yourNewValue</NewValue>
    </Question>
  </Group>
</UpdateTargets>
```

**EDIT BASED ON OP COMMENT**

If you have a static part of your request, you can include the dinamyc part builded with `groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder` as follows:

```
... from previous script
// markup to create the request
def sw = new StringWriter()
def request = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
// create <UpdateTargets>
...

// static data sample 
def staticData = 
'''<Envelope>
    <Header>someData</Header>
    <Body>
        <SomeTags>moreData</SomeTags>
    </Body>
</Envelope>'''
def newRequest = new XmlSlurper().parseText(staticData)
// dinamic part builded with markupBuilder
def dinamicPart = new XmlSlurper().parseText(sw.toString())
// append the <UpdateTargets> to your static part
newRequest.Body.appendNode(dinamicPart)
// serialize the full xml
log.info  groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( newRequest )
```

This will outputs:

```
<Envelope>
   <Header>someData</Header>
   <Body>
      <SomeTags>moreData</SomeTags>
      <UpdateTargets>
         <Group>
            <Question>
               <ID>1234</ID>
               <Row>2</Row>
               <NewValue>yourNewValue</NewValue>
            </Question>
            <Question>
               <ID>2222</ID>
               <Row>3</Row>
               <NewValue>yourNewValue</NewValue>
            </Question>
         </Group>
         <Group>
            <Question>
               <ID>4244</ID>
               <Row>0</Row>
               <NewValue>yourNewValue</NewValue>
            </Question>
         </Group>
      </UpdateTargets>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your assistance. The request I'm building will also contain a header and a few tags at the beginning that won't be repeated. can this method be used to append the dynamic stuff to a request. For example <Envelope><Header>........</Header><Body><Some Tags></Some tags><UpdateTargets>.......dynamic tags ........</UpdateTargets></Body></Envelope>

Comment: @user3803807 I update the answer with your new requeriment, take a look on it `:)`.

Comment: The embed is working fine but I can't get the first part to work. It keeps coming back with just <UpdateTargets/>I'm using the GetCityForecastByZip operation in SoapUI tutorial to test (http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL) and the code I'm using is in the next comment. Can you see anything obviously wrong

Comment: request.UpdateTargets {
    // for each <Group> in response create a group in next
    // request
    root.Forecast.each{ forecast ->
        Forecast {
            // for each <Question> in response create a question in next
            // request
            forecast.WeatherID.each { weatherID ->
                WeatherID(){
                    ID('yourNewValue')
                    Row('yourNewValue')
                    NewValue('yourNewValue')
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}

Comment: The problem is that `<Forecast>` is not directly child of the root node in response, correct the path to `root.Body.GetCityForecastByZIPResponse.GetCityForecastByZIPResult.ForecastResult.Forecast.each {...` alternatively you can use `findAll` as follows: `root.'**'.findAll {
 it.name() == 'Forecast'
}.each{ ...`  . Both expressions do the same and solve your problem however to keep the things clearer for you better use the first approach.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. still can't find the node

def xml = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetCityForecastByZIP').getPropertyValue('response')
root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def sw = new StringWriter()
def request = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
// create <UpdateTargets>
request.UpdateTargets {
    Store("Gav")
    Mine("Gav2")
    Items{
     root.Body.GetCityForecastByZIPResponse.GetCityForecastByZIPResult.ForecastResul‌​t.Forecast.each{forecast->
     Forecast{
      Store2("Gav333")
        }
     }
    }
}
log.info sw

Items is still appearing as <items/> in the log